# Mysql query to get trend of temperature

Tags: mysql, logging, temperature, trend

I have a very large table where I have temperatures getting logged every 1 mins, what I would like to query is a trend; something like a percentage increase or percentage decrease per selected period ( hour or 15mins; depending on the query)

my table looks (example)  like the following

```
ID      time                temp
119950  2013-03-27 07:56:05 27.25
119951  2013-03-27 07:57:05 27.50
119952  2013-03-27 07:58:05 27.60
119953  2013-03-27 07:59:05 27.80
119954  2013-03-27 08:00:05 27.70
119955  2013-03-27 08:01:05 27.50
119956  2013-03-27 08:02:05 27.25
119957  2013-03-27 08:03:05 27.10
119958  2013-03-27 08:04:05 26.9
119959  2013-03-27 08:05:05 27.1
119960  2013-03-27 08:06:05 27.25
119961  2013-03-27 08:07:05 27.6
```

I believe a trend can be calculated as follow (as per [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Rate-of-Temperature-Increase)), but correct me if you have a better way;
take the difference between each row then add then up and divide by count. so for the table above we get

```
Diff
+0.25
+0.10
+0.20
-0.10
-0.20
-0.25
-0.15
-0.20
+0.20
+0.15
+0.35
```

The trend per minute for last 11 minutes is sum of diff/11. which gives 0.063C per minute for last 11minutes.

Can someone please help me get percentage trend per hour for last 3 hours. and trend per minute for 1 hour?

Comment: Observe that the sum of all those differences is equal to the difference between the initial and final values.  Percentage change can therefore be obtained from `final/initial - 1` - e.g. `27.6/27.25 - 1 ~= +1.28%`.

Comment: Thanks, but the above table is just an example. this is an exception. generally the values will be all over the place and the sum of all differences will not equal the dif between initial and final.

Comment: No - the sum of all differences will *always* equal the difference between initial and final, due to the associativity of addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE temperature_log
(ID      INT NOT NULL,dt DATETIME NOT NULL, temperature DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO temperature_log VALUES
(119950  ,'2013-03-27 07:56:05',27.25),
(119951  ,'2013-03-27 07:57:05', 27.50),
(119952  ,'2013-03-27 07:58:05', 27.60),
(119953  ,'2013-03-27 07:59:05', 27.80),
(119954  ,'2013-03-27 08:00:05', 27.70),
(119955  ,'2013-03-27 08:01:05', 27.50),
(119956  ,'2013-03-27 08:02:05', 27.25),
(119957  ,'2013-03-27 08:03:05', 27.10),
(119958  ,'2013-03-27 08:04:05', 26.9),
(119959  ,'2013-03-27 08:05:05', 27.1),
(119960  ,'2013-03-27 08:06:05', 27.25),
(119961  ,'2013-03-27 08:07:05', 27.6);

SELECT x.*
     , x.temperature - y.temperature diff
     , COUNT(*) cnt
     ,(x.temperature-y.temperature)/COUNT(*) trend 
  FROM temperature_log x 
  JOIN temperature_log y 
    ON y.id < x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id;
+--------+---------------------+-------------+-------+-----+-----------+
| ID     | dt                  | temperature | diff  | cnt | trend     |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+-------+-----+-----------+
| 119951 | 2013-03-27 07:57:05 |       27.50 |  0.25 |   1 |  0.250000 |
| 119952 | 2013-03-27 07:58:05 |       27.60 |  0.35 |   2 |  0.175000 |
| 119953 | 2013-03-27 07:59:05 |       27.80 |  0.55 |   3 |  0.183333 |
| 119954 | 2013-03-27 08:00:05 |       27.70 |  0.45 |   4 |  0.112500 |
| 119955 | 2013-03-27 08:01:05 |       27.50 |  0.25 |   5 |  0.050000 |
| 119956 | 2013-03-27 08:02:05 |       27.25 |  0.00 |   6 |  0.000000 |
| 119957 | 2013-03-27 08:03:05 |       27.10 | -0.15 |   7 | -0.021429 |
| 119958 | 2013-03-27 08:04:05 |       26.90 | -0.35 |   8 | -0.043750 |
| 119959 | 2013-03-27 08:05:05 |       27.10 | -0.15 |   9 | -0.016667 |
| 119960 | 2013-03-27 08:06:05 |       27.25 |  0.00 |  10 |  0.000000 |
| 119961 | 2013-03-27 08:07:05 |       27.60 |  0.35 |  11 |  0.031818 |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+-------+-----+-----------+
```

Incidentally, if you're interested in getting average results per hour, you could do something like this...

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(x.dt,'%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00')
     , AVG(x.temperature) avg_temp
  FROM temperature_log x 
 GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(x.dt,'%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00');
```

Comment: Thanks, but since I 100 of thansands of values, would you be able to insert a filter to get hourly temperatures for a period of 3 hours?

Comment: Yes, but that's a different question. It would be inappropriate to amend the answer without first amending the question (or accepting it and then asking a new one).

Comment: I really appreciate your help, Thank you :). my original question does mention this, as I have so much data; i cannot see if your answer works, it will take soooo looong to get result for everything,  if!

Comment: OK, in that case can you explain how the percentage trend per hour is calculated? Googling "percentage trend per hour" only returns this page, which suggests it's something you've just invented!

Comment: What you have calculated is perfect I believe,  I need to limit the data pulled from my database. i.e if i apply your query above, my query will timeout because it will need to pull all the 120000 values. but if you could add a: SELECT DATE(time) + INTERVAL (HOUR(time) DIV 1 * 1) HOUR and WHERE DATE(time) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOURS, something like this.

Comment: OK, I'll think about that - but 120000 rows is trivial. ID is a PRIMARY KEY, right?

Comment: yes correct, see my dilemma; I cannot use the above solution unless i introduce a filter

Comment: Wouldn't an hour-to-hour trend normally be calculated by comparing average values for each hour?

Comment: meaning calculate average for 1hour and compare that with the average of the previous hour, that sound great : something like  ((x.average.hour.temperature - y.average.hour.temperature))/2

Comment: Hm, then I think you have enough now to figure that out for yourself ;-)

Comment: the last piece of puzzle for me to become better at mysql queries is this part, how would i get average for 1 hour and subtract it with average of the earlier hour?

Answer (score 0):

I know the subject is old but if i can share with you my experience.
maybe this can be usefull for the next people :)

I've a very large table with temperature of my all devices (100+) and all my devices push every 5 secondes the temperatures (one device has 6 zones of vision, and i can get the temperature of each zone).

So the table is very big. For me the previous response is not efficient with lot of data.
See what i do:

This is the schema of my large table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `histozone` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `camera_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `Time` TIME NOT NULL,
    `ZoneId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `AverageTemperature` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `MinimumTemperature` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `MaximumTemperature` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `IDX_19E8F664B47685CD` (`camera_id`),
    INDEX `datetime` (`camera_id`, `Date`, `Time`),
);
```

Like you can see, I've the `Date` and `Time` for each row.

1. Create a temporary table for each device with the MEMORY Engine in my PHP code. I restrict the tmp table in a duration (date and time).

```sql
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS histoZoneMaxTempCamera{$cameraId};
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE histoZoneMaxTempCamera{$cameraId} (
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `originalid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `time` TIME NOT NULL,
    `zoneid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `maximumtemperature` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    INDEX (`maximumtemperature`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY;
INSERT INTO histoZoneMaxTempCamera{$cameraId} (`originalid`, `date`, `time`, `zoneid`, `maximumtemperature`)
    SELECT
        h.id,
        h.Date,
        h.Time,
        h.ZoneId,
        h.MaximumTemperature
    FROM histozone h

    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            hz.camera_id,
            MAX(hz.MaximumTemperature) AS MaximumTemperature,
            hz.Date,
            hz.Time
        FROM histozone hz
        WHERE hz.camera_id = '{$cameraId}'
            AND hz.Date >= '{$date}'
            AND hz.Time >= '{$time}'
        GROUP BY hz.Date, hz.Time
    ) histozoneMaxTemp 
        ON  h.Date = histozoneMaxTemp.Date
        AND h.Time = histozoneMaxTemp.Time
        AND h.MaximumTemperature = histozoneMaxTemp.MaximumTemperature

    WHERE h.camera_id = histozoneMaxTemp.camera_id
    ORDER BY h.Date ASC, h.Time ASC;
```

2. And the last step, is to get the data, the trend, etc ... Me, I only wanted the fluctuating temperature points. It's not interesting to have a graph with a lot of points at the same level.

```
SELECT 
a.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        x.id AS xid
        , x.Date AS `Date`
        , x.Time AS `Time`
        , x.maximumtemperature AS maximumtemperature
        , y.maximumtemperature AS previousmaximumtemperature
        , x.maximumtemperature - y.maximumtemperature diff
        ,(x.maximumtemperature-y.maximumtemperature)/MAX(x.id) trend 
    FROM histoZoneMaxTempCamera{$cameraId} x
    LEFT JOIN histoZoneMaxTempCamera{$cameraId} y
        ON y.id = (x.id - 1)
    GROUP BY x.id
) a
WHERE a.trend <> (
        SELECT b.trend
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                x.id AS xid
                ,(x.maximumtemperature-y.maximumtemperature)/MAX(x.id) trend 
            FROM histoZoneMaxTempCamera{$cameraId} x
            LEFT JOIN histoZoneMaxTempCamera{$cameraId} y
                ON y.id = (x.id - 1)
            GROUP BY x.id
        ) b
        WHERE b.xid = a.xid - 1
    ) OR a.xid = 1
;
```

This works perfectly, and is super fast even with a very large starting table.