# Calculating the tendency of a value over time

Tags: mysql, math, calculated-columns

I've got a table with (amongst other values) the temperature for the last 4 hours. When making a graph of it I can see the 'tendency' of the graph on an eye blink:

[image]

The thick red line obviously has a negative direction. While the green line has a positive direction.

How can I calculate this 'direction' value of the last 3 hours worth of data. This data can be retreived from the database with the following sql-statement:

```
SELECT temp FROM weather WHERE time_utc => NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR
```

Is there a function like AVG() or something to calculate this or am I overthinking this?

Comment: Consider the problems of sampling the data over different time scales.  If sampled once per hour (or day or month), even though intermediate values are wildly higher and lower than the samples, what meaning is there for *tendency*?   That is, a better specification of what the result *means* is needed.

Comment: Can you change the schema so that when inserting new weather, you have another diff_temp column which is the difference between the new one and the last one?

Comment: Maybe we have different eyes, As @wallyk said you need specify the rules to determinate tendency because for me the red line was stable until  start decline a litle bit in third block. But if you see second block the red line has a spike. So could be Increase or Decrease tendency at that time.

Comment: The graph shows more than three hours of data. So indeed in the middle of the red line the 'result' should be 'stable'; on the left of it it should be + and on the right negative. The data is sampled every 10 seconds. Could it be as simple as retrieving the data at now()-3hours and calculate the diff?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql query to get trend of temperature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762585/mysql-query-to-get-trend-of-temperature)

Comment: now() - [3 hours] is one definition.  Does that give a sensible result?  What about now() - [10 seconds ago]?  Or average(last hour) - average (previous hour)?

Comment: @wallyk that's a good question. 10 seconds will be to short, while 24 hour would make no sense.
The thing I want to show is a little triangle next to the value in my dashboard denoting a rise or a fall in temp.

Comment: Maybe the time interval for the delta should be a user preference?  Or maybe there could be say 3 triangles, showing the trend over the last minute, 15 minutes, and 3 hours?

Answer (score 1):

What about this :

```
  SELECT HOUR(time_utc) as  hour_group, AVG(temp) 
  FROM weather 
  WHERE time_utc => NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR
  GROUP BY hour_group
```

This way you divide your measures in hour block and can compare the first with the last?